# primefaces with spring-data abstract controller

Tags: spring, primefaces, maven-3, spring-data-jpa, jsf-2.2

I want you to say me if what i do is right. 
I have a maven project:
Parent is core
modules are :
entity
Dto
repository
service
controller
web
security

my first class just to illustrate

>

```
@Table(name = "address")
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String streetNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String postalCode;
    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
    private String website;
    private String mail;
    private String tel_1;
    private String tel_2;
    private String fax_1;
    private String fax_2;

    public Address() {
        super();
    }
```

> Blockquote

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.RestResource;
import com.entities.Address;

@RestResource(rel="address", path="address")
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Integer>{

}
```

> Blockquote

```
import interfaces.IAddressService;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.entities.Address;

import dto.AddressDTO;

@Service
@Transactional
public class AddressService extends GenericServiceImpl<Address, AddressDTO, Long> implements IAddressService{


}
```

> Blockquote

```
package services;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public class GenericServiceImpl<T, D, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericService<T, D, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<T, ID> repository;

    @Autowired
    private DozerBeanMapper mapper;

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    protected Class<D> dtoClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericServiceImpl() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        this.dtoClass = (Class<D>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    public D findOne(ID id) {
        return mapper.map(repository.findOne(id), dtoClass);
    }

    public List<D> findAll() {
        List<D> result = new ArrayList<D>();
        for (T t : repository.findAll()) {
            result.add(mapper.map(t, dtoClass));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void save(D dto) {
        repository.saveAndFlush(mapper.map(dto, entityClass));
    }

    public void removeById(int id) {
        repository.delete(mapper.map(id, entityClass));
    }

}
```

> Blockquote

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public interface GenericService <T, D, ID extends Serializable>{

    D findOne(ID id);

    List<D> findAll();

    void save(D dto);

}
```

> Blockquote

```
import services.GenericService;

import com.entities.Address;

import dto.AddressDTO;

public interface IAddressService extends GenericService<Address, AddressDTO, Long> {

}
```

> Blockquote

```
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import services.AddressService;
import dto.AddressDTO;

@Named(value = "addressController")
@ViewScoped
public class AddressController extends AbstractController<AddressDTO> {

    @Inject
    AddressService addressService;
}
```

> Blockquote

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import controller.util.JsfUtil;

public abstract class AbstractController<T> {

    @Inject
    private AbstractFacade<T> ejbFacade;
    private Class<T> itemClass;
    private T selected;
    private Collection<T> items;

    private enum PersistAction {

        CREATE,
        DELETE,
        UPDATE
    }

    public AbstractController() {
    }

    public AbstractController(Class<T> itemClass) {
        this.itemClass = itemClass;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the currently selected item
     *
     * @return
     */
    public T getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    /**
     * Pass in the currently selected item
     *
     * @param selected
     */
    public void setSelected(T selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
```

> Blockquote

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }


    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

I'm sorry i put a lot of code.
The probleme is AbstractController and AbstractFacade.
AbstractFacade i need it in my projec?
The goal is to make the same functions for all controllers (CRUD) by passing by AbstractController and AbstractFacade.
I'm using Primefaces with spring-data and multi-module maven project.
what i want if it's not very clear is to make life easy if i want to add any service(because i have more than classe in my package entity which is my POJO)
I retrieve AbstractController and AbstractFacade from the net and i want to adapt for my project.
If you dont understand i can give more informations.
it's to do the same thing as genericService with my services( i speak of the principle) and the interest is to refactor the code.
thank you.

Comment: 'code snippets' are only for html/javascript. Can you edit your code? But how is this PrimeFaces or JSF or Maven related?

Comment: sorry but i did with without snippet but the code is very bad, i dont know why. for the maven i use it only to downlaod dependencies. i hope i'm clear

Comment: I modified the code.

Comment: Conclusion : i think i dont need AbstractFacade in my project. in each controller i inject service with have CRUD functions from JpaRepository. what do you think? thanks

Comment: What is the point AbstractFacade given Spring Data's concrete implementation of JpaRepository will do precisely the same thing?